# How to get and show all product details on success page in OpenCart 2.x

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I have searched but only found details for opencart 1.5. I tried using

```
$this->load->model('account/order');
```

but throws an error because it only works for earlier versions of opencart. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->load->model('checkout/order');
$order_info=$this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying however the error still shows: 

`Notice: Undefined property: Loader::$load in /...
Fatal error: Call to a member function model() on a non-object in/..`.

I think the problem is to do with `$this->load->model` in opencart 2.0 there must be a new way to call the object. 

Thanks for help.